# How to keep out utility functions in a separate directory inside an app in Django

Tags: django

In my current project, I have moved out most of the business logic from my views and have put them under the following directory structure **myapp/utility/utility.py**. Under the Utility directory i have put the **init**.py file also. I am using most of the models from my Models.py file in the utils.py file. Now the problem I am facing is when I run python manage.py runserver, it throws up an error saying **models not found**.
I had also followed the steps listed in the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage). The project structure can be seen below. The following are just below my app directory.
In the utils.py I am trying to do the import

```
from my_project.myapp.models import Location, Product
```

This where it is not working.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Can you post directory structure and code where you import models?

Comment: have edited the question with the directory structure and import statement.

Answer (score 1):

In Django you may import from project's root directory directly, so in your case it should be something like this:

```
from myapp.models import Location, Product
```

Comment: I have tried the above import statement, still it is not working.

Comment: @AR7 hm.. does `manage.py` located inside `my_project` directory directly? And `myapp` also?

Comment: It's located in the my_project directory only.

Comment: @AR7 so it looks like this: `my_project/manage.py` and `my_project/myapp/models.py`?

Comment: Yes it looks exactly that way

Comment: @AR7 can you add full traceback to the question?

Comment: it is just showing particular model cannot be imported

Comment: @AR7 can you post what exaclty error message tells? Also can you add models.py file?

Comment: in the utils.py file on the top line i had written import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application() and the error it shows now is RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant